# Can I run services from other mounted linux os?

Tags: services

Hey i don't have Network Manager package on my ubuntuserver os , but I have that package in ubuntu which is a dual boot in my computer.Can I mount that partition with ubuntu server and run Networkmanager service/any service from there..

Comment: Is this just a theoretical question, or is there an issue with the existing networking service on the server that you are hoping to solve this way?

Comment: hi thanku for your reply .Using systemd-nspawn we can run other containers but the problem is that I don't have a network manager package on that os ,so sharing of network is not possible .Can u please tell me is there a way to share network connection to it.